# I am trying to use WMI to trigger an SSIS package when a file is created

Tags: ssis, wmi, visual-studio-2022

I have a working SSIS package but I have not had any luck getting it to trigger.  I have a query that will parse but it simply waits even when I create a file in the monitored location.

One wrinkle is that the file creation and SQL environment are not on the server I am doing the development on.  I am using Visual Studio 2022 to do the development.

This is my first SSIS package as well as the first time I have used Visual Studio so the more details I can get the better.

The expression is:

```
   "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE 
   TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND TargetInstance.Drive = 'pr-az-sql01' AND 
    TargetInstance.Path = '"+ REPLACE( @[User::Path], "\\", "\\\\")  +"' AND 
   TargetInstance.FileName LIKE '"+ @[User::FileNamePrefix] +"%' AND 
    TargetInstance.Extension = '"+ @[User::FileExtension] +"'"
```

Which results in:

```
    `SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE 
   TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND TargetInstance.Drive = 'pr-az-sql01' AND 
   TargetInstance.Path = '\\workmax reports\\Progressive\\' AND 
    TargetInstance.FileName LIKE 'Progressive Report Data%' AND 
    TargetInstance.Extension = 'xlsx'`
```

I have tried replacing the 'pr-az-sql01' with the local drive 'G:' with the same results.
I have tried replacing TargetInstance.drive and everything that comes after with the entered file path but that resulted in an unparsabl query.